# Debugging in IntelliJ gives "Address localhost:1099 is already in use" error

Tags: content-delivery, java

I am running a Tridion based (DXA) JAVA web application in IntelliJ. The Run/Debug configuration is based on the standard Local Tomcat server settings.

When I stop the debugging session and start again to try again I get this error in the IntelliJ Event Log

```
2:12:06 PM All files are up-to-date
2:12:09 PM Error running Tomcat local 8080: Address localhost:1099 is already in use
2:12:12 PM Error running Tomcat local 8080: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:59985): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"
```

This only occurs when the ObjectCache with RemoteSynchronization is enabled in the CD storage config (cd_storage_conf.xml) of the webapp.

```
<Configuration Version="7.1">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
            <RemoteSynchronization Queuesize="512">
                <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion" Strategy="AsyncJMS11">
                    <JndiContext>
```

I see that there are multiple JAVA process running after the debug session is stopped. After I kill them the debug session starts normal without errors.

Is it normal that processes keep running after a debug session? How can I stop the right processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure that you only make and deploy the project once, else two processes will get started, while port 1099 is started in deployment 1, but your debugging session actually happens on deployment 2.

If you use maven, you only need to set the following line in your Make configuration:

[image]

If you don't use Maven, then choose to either only Make the project, or to only choose to Build the Artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Raimond said](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12945/88): only build once. The problem was a bug in the Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ. I did both `Make` and `Build webapp artifact`. Without the fist `make` step it works fine.

[image]

It turns out that that confuses IntelliJ, in this case I only need a Build webapp artifact.

Answer (score 1):

changing the JMX port from  1099 to 1000 did the trick for me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HspFB.png

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound right, but as a workaround I use [this script](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/07156b3370c7a9c58a54) to kill Java processes which come from IntelliJ. This does not kill the IntelliJ IDE itself.

```
$processes = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'java.exe'"

foreach($proc in $processes)
{
    if($proc.CommandLine.Contains("IntelliJ"))
    {
        Write-Host "stopping proccess $($proc.ProcessId) with $($proc.ThreadCount) threads; $($proc.CommandLine.Substring(0, 50))..."
        Stop-Process -F $proc.ProcessId
    } else
    {
        Write-Host "skipping proccess $($proc.ProcessId) with $($proc.ThreadCount) threads; $($proc.CommandLine.Substring(0, 50))..."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a port much larger than 1024. Windows blocks the use of frequently used ports. Use e.g. 5588